# What's the proper word for this description?

Tags: word-request

If the woman in this picture is "covered head woman" (=with a cover on the head such cap etc.) then the man in this picture is "uncovered head man" (=without any cover on the head) or "discovered head man"?

I'd like to know how to refer to this aspect of the head cover by adjectives, as above.

> "I saw two people speaking each other: one was (**head uncovered?**) man and the second
> was (**head covered?**) woman."

[image: A man and a woman talking]

The photo is from [this site](https://assetsnffrgf-a.akamaihd.net/assets/m/1102014622/univ/art/1102014622_univ_sqr_xl.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be idiomatic to make *covered head* into an attributive adjective that appears before the noun **woman**.

> ... covered-head woman <sup>NO</sup>

But we can say

> ... a woman, *her head covered*, is speaking with (or perhaps listening to) a man whose head is uncovered.

Answer (score 1):

The usual term for a person without any hat or covering for the head is [*bareheaded*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bareheaded) (sometimes seen *bare-headed*).  That would be the appropriate term here.

For the woman in your picture, it would be better to describe the covering.  Her head was covered by a cowl or shawl would be appropriate.